# Unhandled exception operator overloading

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am practicing with operator overloading and have built a simple calculator.

```
template <class one> class calc {
    int a;
public:
    calc() : a(0) {};
    calc(const calc& other) : a(other.a) {}
    void print() { cout << a; }
    calc& operator += (const calc& other);
    calc& operator += (const one& i);
    calc& operator -= (const calc& other);
    calc& operator -= (const one& i);
    calc& operator *= (const calc& other);
    calc& operator *= (const one& i);
    calc& operator /= (const calc& other);
    calc& operator /= (const one& i);
    const calc& operator - () const;
    friend const calc operator + (const calc& our, const calc& other);
    friend const calc operator + (const one& i, const calc& other);
    friend const calc operator + (const calc& our, const one& i);
 };
```

But unfortunately, when I try to implement the class, it throws the exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x010154C9 in Proctical programming c++
>   overloading 1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001,
>   0x00192F64).

Here is the `main`:

```
int main() {
    calc <int> one;
    one += 2;
    one.print();
    cin.get();
}
```

And the problem occurs, for example, here but consequently also in other operators:

```
template <class one>
calc<one>& calc <one> :: operator += (const one& i) {
    *this += i;
    return *this;
}
```

Could you, please, hint me at what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what is the exception?  And why are you calling `+=` from `+=`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have edited the question

Comment: So where is the actual `+=` stuff being done?  All you're doing is recursively calling `+=` from `+=`.  In other words, I see no code to do an actual addition.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a += i`?  Also `a` should be `one a;` not `int a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function calls itself recursively with no condition to exit:

```
template <class one>
calc<one>& calc <one> :: operator += (const one& i) {
    *this += i;
    //    ^calls the function youre currently in.
    return *this;
}
```

You need to adjust your `+=` operator to use the `+` operator that you've defined, or as @PaulMcKenzie stated, do the actual addition in `+=` and have `+` use `+=`. For example,

```
template <class one>
calc<one>& calc <one> :: operator += (const one& i) {
    a += i;
    return *this;
}
```

seems to work.

You can see a warning about this if your warning level is high enough:

> Warning    1   warning C4717: 'calc::operator+=' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow

That being said, there are some other problems with your code, like `int a` should be `one a` and

```
friend const calc operator + (const calc& our, const calc& other);
```

should just be a normal `+` operator instead of a friend.

Comment: Actually, it is better to implement the low-level code in `operator +=`, not `operator +`, and let `operator +` call `operator +=`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie cool, good to know.  I'll edit to be a little more clear about that.